# delete record from table only not affect in database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

If I try to delete record from table but how to use it, I don't know.

In a radgrid I hav use delete link if I have press delete it's I'll be work but I have try to next level of delete.

If I press delete that data I'll be delete on the grid but it's not affect on Sql database but we don't store data from other table can explain how to use it.

```
<Telerik:RadGrid ID="GVUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="false" GridLines="None"
                                                                      CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Skin="WebBlue"
                                                                      AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1000" Height="360PX" Width="100%">


  <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="2" />
    <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" />
  </ClientSettings>
  <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="pendingdump_gid">
    <Columns>
      <Telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox id="chkall" Text="Select" runat="server" Checked="false" onclick="javascript:select_deselectAll (this.checked, this.id, 'chkall','chkupload');" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkupload" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Checked="false" onclick="javascript:select_deselectAll (this.checked, this.id, 'chkall','chkupload');" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </Telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_gid" HeaderText="Cust ID" Visible="false"
          ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"  ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_refno" HeaderText="Ref.No." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="30%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_name" HeaderText="Party's Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_amount" HeaderText="Pending Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_duedate" HeaderText="Due On" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pendingdump_overduedays" HeaderText="Overdue by Days" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ></Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <Telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="30%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" >
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Click to Delete"
               OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmDelete();" CommandName="lnkbtnDelete" CommandArgument=''
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pendingdump_gid") %>'>
          </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </Telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  </MasterTableView>
</Telerik:RadGrid>
```

---

```
      Protected Sub GVUpload_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles GVUpload.ItemCommand

            lblerrmsg.Text = ""

            If e.CommandName = "lnkbtnDelete" Then

                Gobjdbconn.OpenConn()

                MsSql = ""
                MsSql = "Delete vsolv_tmp_tpendingdump where pendingdump_gid = '" & e.CommandArgument() & "' and pendingdump_isremoved = 'N'"

                MnResult = Gobjdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(MsSql)

                If MnResult = 1 Then
                    lblerrmsg.Text = "Record Deleted Successfully"
                Else
                    lblerrmsg.Text = "Record not Deleted"
                End If

                POPSummary()

            End If


        End Sub
```

Comment: So, is that `ItemCommand` event handler executing or not?  If so, is `MnResult` equal to 1 or not?

Comment: Did you declare `MsSql` as SqlCommand?

Comment: sql command  i hav use